# Keep all tabs of accordion menu closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu, accordion

I have a simple accordion menu in my Archives, the first menu item is always open but how do I amend the JS so that all menu items are closed on pageload? URL is http://helloarchie.blue/archives

JS

```
function openFirstPanel(){
$('.accordion > dt:first-child').next().addClass('active').slideDown();
}

(function($) {

var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();

openFirstPanel();

$('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
  $this = $(this);
  $target =  $this.parent().next();


  if($target.hasClass('active')){
    $target.removeClass('active').slideUp(); 
  }else{
    allPanels.removeClass('active').slideUp();
    $target.addClass('active').slideDown();
  }

return false;
});
```

Comment: remove the `openFirstPanel()` function? ...

Comment: Had to remove the first function as you suggested and the 'openFirstPanel();' underneath.

Comment: placed as answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `openFirstPanel()` function and the call for the function.

So you get this:

```
(function($) {

    var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();
    $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        $target =  $this.parent().next();
        if($target.hasClass('active')){
            $target.removeClass('active').slideUp(); 
        }else{
             allPanels.removeClass('active').slideUp();
             $target.addClass('active').slideDown();
         }

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score -2):

> Setting active to false will collapse all panels. This requires the collapsible option to be true.
>   http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/

```
$('.accordion').accordion({
    active: false,
    collapsible: true            
});
```

Comment: A little explanation and reference links would be great, second I don't see any jQuery UI - Accordion in OPs code